# Is it possible to save the prepared PDF for the signing using pdfbox and finish it later?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, digital-signature

I know the possibility of using ExternalSigningSupport in order to do the PDF signing. But it requires obtaining and storing the signature just after, in same thread. I would like to store prepared content on the disk and pick up it sometime later. Does pdfbox has some API allowing this, just using the prepared content?

Imagine something like

```
ExternalSigningSupport externalSigning = document.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning(outputStream);
file = saveToFile(externalSigning.getContent());
document.close()
```

and possibly in another thread, another day:

```
byte[] hash = calculateHash(file);
byte[] signature = sign(hash);
try (PDDocument document = loadPreparedDocumentForSigning(file)) {
    document.setSignature(signature);
}
```

Comment: The `CreateVisibleSignature.java`  and `CreateVisibleSignature.java` examples have a switch `lateExternalSigning` that facilitates that.

Answer (score 0):

As Tilman answered in the comment, there is a working example how to do this in [CreateVisibleSignature](https://apache.googlesource.com/pdfbox/+/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/CreateVisibleSignature.java), just search for "late external signing".